# Leaflet list marker options

Tags: leaflet

I would need some information on list markers:

- how can I change the opacity of the list and also the background color
- how can I set the overflow so that if the markers in the list increase, they scroll through the
  scrollbar?
  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly not a leaflet element, to change the transparency of the object that you specified, you most likely need to change these properties in the css, try using DeveloperTools in the browser to find where this object takes the properties (transparency) from and you will know how to change it correctly.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNtRx.png)

Comment: thanks I solved the problem, from the css I also set the overflow

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, here is an approximate way to do what you ask in the first part of the question. Show your code what it looks like now.

```
.className {
    background: white;
    } 
    
    
    let marker = L.circle([50.0], [40.0]], {opacity: 1}).addTo(map),
    marker.className = "className";
```

Comment: Hello,
thanks for the reply, i updated the question if you know how to help me would you do me a favor, thanks

Answer (score 0):

no I don't mean the transparency of the single marker but of the list, I send a photo in which the list is circled.
I don't know in which part of the library to act to give properties to this list element.[image]

Comment: Are you sure that that box is part of leaflet? It seems a custom box

Comment: Don't use answers to questions as a forum: if you need to provide further information on the original question, edit it and add the extra info, don't post a new answer (which isnt)